# Link Windows installer through bit.ly?

Tags: links, url-shortening, bit.ly

I have released a Windows installer as open-source software (it is a well-known software with peer-reviewed article in scientific journal) and wanted to get some download metrics with bit.ly service, to see how it goes. My exe is on my dropbox account, since I don't have the money or support to buy hosting for this thing.

When I test the Windows link it redirects me to a page

> Stop - there might be a problem with the requested link
>
> The link you requested has been identified by bitly as being potentially problematic. This could be because a bitly user has reported a problem, a black-list service reported a problem, because the link has been shortened more than once, or because we have detected potentially malicious content. This may be a problem because:
>
> Some URL-shorteners re-use their links, so bitly can't guarantee the validity of this link.
>
> Some URL-shorteners allow their links to be edited, so bitly can't tell where this link will lead you.
>
> Spam and malware is very often propagated by exploiting these loopholes, neither of which bitly allows for.
>
> The link you requested may contain inappropriate content, or even spam or malicious code that could be downloaded to your computer without your consent, or may be a forgery or imitation of another website, designed to trick users into sharing personal or financial information.
>
> bitly suggests that you
>
> - Change the original link, and re-shorten with bitly
> - Close your browser window
> - Notify the sender of the URL
>
> Or, continue at your own risk

I have scanned my installer through the JOTTI virus scan and no anti-virus reports a even a single warning, my file is clean. I couldn't find any reference on how to solve this problem.

Is there any way to link an installer through bit.ly?

Is there anything else I can check?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like what you are trying to do is considered suspicious activity by bitly. This seems to be related to you using two different unrelated services (Dropbox and Bitly). I don't think there is an "I'm an honest person" checkbox that you could mark to solve this.

Suggestions:

1. Try another shortener, such as goo.gl (which also provides click analytics).
2. If the problem persists, try a hosting & analytics combination from the same company (Google Drive and goo.gl, for example).